# How to check if a file is tab-delimited and has 8 columns?

Tags: text-processing

I have two things I need to check a text file for:

1. If it is tab-delimited
2. If it has exactly 8 columns

How can I check those things and show an error message if either is false?

Comment: A plain text file with no tab characters at all could well be a tab-delimited file that happens to have one field per line.

Comment: Is this really tab delimited, or is it merely tab separated?

Answer (score 9):

One solution is to use awk:

```
awk -F "\t" 'NF != 8' data.txt
```

This command will print out those lines in the file data.txt which does not have 8 fields.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a perl oneliner, like so:

```
perl -ne '(s/\t//go)==7 or die "Not tabdelimitedand 8-columned"' t.txt
```

Which will exit with an error message if the file does not conform. To allow further (bash) scripting:

```
if perl -ne '(s/\t//go)==7 or exit -1' t.txt
then
    echo correct format
else
    echo unexpected format
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ct=($(sed -re 's/[^\t]//g' "$file" | expand -t1 | wc -l -c -L))

if (( ((ct[0] * 8) == ct[1]) && (ct[2] == 7) )) ;then
    echo "file contains 8 tab-delimited fields on every line"
else 
    if (( ct[1] == ct[0] )) ;then
        echo "file does not contain any tab-delimiters"
    else
        echo "file contains tabs, but does not have 8 fields on every line"
    fi
fi
```